# How can I set a custom timeout for a chainlink node/external adapter?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, chainlink

It seems that the [external adapter](https://github.com/thodges-gh/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template) has a maximum timeout of 3000ms. My query takes a while to run, and I need it to be 30000ms. Does anyone know if there is a parameter I can change or set either within the external adapter or within my chainlink node?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You'll want to make an attempt and show some code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look within the requester.js package (that should have installed after running npm install) you will find the following code:

```
class Requester {
  static request (config, customError, retries = 3, delay = 1000) {
    if (typeof config === 'string') config = { url: config }
    if (typeof config.timeout === 'undefined') {
      const timeout = Number(process.env.TIMEOUT)
      config.timeout = !isNaN(timeout) ? timeout : 3000
    }
```

You could set the timeout via the process environment variable or keep that undefined and change the conditional falsy value as shown below:

`config.timeout = !isNaN(timeout) ? timeout : 30000`